# Resource limit breaching with Higher number of concurrent pods in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, containers, kubectl

One of our microservice(worker component - nature is short lived) is actually getting deployed on K8s pods in an autoscale fashion, sometimes this number goes to few thousands as well based upon load and this worker is bound to make connections with various persistent services, since these services come with some resource limit, so we're getting bottlenecked at access level, so my ask is, do we have some way in Kubernetes(similar to some sort of gateway/proxy) which narrow down multiplex requests to limit under resource limits. Let's say every pod makes a connection to MySQL server which has an active connection limit of 50, so if we keep spinning new pods(requirement of 1 MySQL connection), then we can not spin more than 50 pods concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

You can setup a [Pod Quota for a Namespace](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-pod-namespace/).

If you can spin those Pods on a separate Namespace, you can limit the number of running pods with creating a `ResourceQuota` object, lets call is `quota-pod.yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: pod-demo
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "2"
```

`kubectl create -f quota-pod.yaml --namespace=quota-pod-example`

If you check `kubectl get resourcequota pod-demo --namespace=quota-pod-example --output=yaml`, you would get something like:

```
spec:
  hard:
    pods: "2"
status:
  hard:
    pods: "2"
  used:
    pods: "0"
```

In the description of the for example 3 replica nginx deployment you would see:

```
Replicas:               1 desired | 1 updated | 1 total | 1 available | 0 unavailable

...  

Events:
  Type    Reason             Age   From                   Message
  ----    ------             ----  ----                   -------
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  2m    deployment-controller  Scaled up replica set nginx-1-7cb5b65464 to 3
  Normal  ScalingReplicaSet  16s   deployment-controller  Scaled down replica set nginx-1-7cb5b65464 to 1
```

And `kubectl get deployment nginx -o yaml` would show:

```
...
status:
  availableReplicas: 1
  conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-12-05T10:42:45Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-12-05T10:42:45Z
    message: Deployment does not have minimum availability.
    reason: MinimumReplicasUnavailable
    status: "False"
    type: Available
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-12-05T10:42:45Z
    lastUpdateTime: 2018-12-05T10:42:45Z
    message: 'pods "nginx-6bd764c757-4gkfq" is forbidden: exceeded quota: pod-demo,
      requested: pods=1, used: pods=2, limited: pods=2'
```

I recommend checking K8s docs [Create a ResourceQuota](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/manage-resources/quota-pod-namespace/#create-a-resourcequota) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for answering @Crou, as I can understand resource quota would allow way to restrict number of pod creation, but in our case we do not want to restrict pod creation.

Comment: So you mean you just want to limit the connection?

Comment: yes, we find something called proxysql for restricting connections to MySQL